# Looping each row in file1.txt over all rows of file2.txt for comparing

Tags: python, awk

I have two text files, say file1.txt contains something like

100.145 10.0728

100.298 10.04

and file2.txt contains something like

100.223 8.92739

100.209 9.04269

100.084 9.08411

100.023 9.01252

I want to compare column 1 and column 2 of both files and print match if the difference of both columns in file1.txt and in file2.txt is less or equal to 0.001.

since both files don't have equal no. or rows, i want row1 of file1.txt to be compared with all the rows of file2.txt, then it will now pick row2 of file1.txt and do same until all rows of file1.txt are exhausted. Difference should like this ($1 file1.txt - $1 file2.txt) and ($2 file1.txt - $2 file2.txt) if difference of both is less or equal 0.001, it should print the rows in both file that match

Comment: Don't ask us to work with "something like" your input and produce "something like" your output. Don't be vague about your requirements, be specific - show us THE input you want a tool to work on and THE output you want given that input.

Comment: Last time you asked this same question you were asked to provide the expected output and as you didn't, apparently you didn't get a pleasing solution. Please do it this time. Also, someone edited your question to more a understandable format. Please, see from your previous question how it was formated to its present form and apply those methods to this question also,

Answer (score -1):

you can try this;

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do  
 while read line2; do  
    Col1F1=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
    Col1F2=$(echo $line2 | awk '{print $1}')
    Col2F1=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}')
    Col2F2=$(echo $line2 | awk '{print $2}')

        if [ ! -z "${Col1F1}" ] && [ ! -z "${Col1F2}" ]; then

         diffCol1=$(awk '{print $1-$2}' <<< "$Col1F1 $Col1F2")
         diffCol2=$(awk '{print $1-$2}' <<< "$Col2F1 $Col2F2")

            if (( $(echo "$diffCol1 < 0.001" |bc -l) && $(echo "$diffCol2 < 0.001" |bc -l))); then
                echo -e ${Col1F1} "\t" ${Col2F1} "\t" ${Col1F2} "\t" ${Col2F2} "\n"
            fi

        fi
 done < file2.txt
done < file1.txt
```